# Android: Gate Drift Asphalt Nitro

Tags: android, asphalt-8

I have been playing Asphalt Nitro on my Samsung Nexus 10" tab. I couldn't even clear a single "Gate Drift" task.

How I drift:

When I see there is Right turn coming I press on right side (I want controls on tab, don't prefer gyroscope movement) of tab and apply breaks. It slows me down and then I have to regain speed.

I searched how to pass "gate drift" tasks on YouTube:

1. Why there car is not stopping when they apply breaks?
2. There car is blowing smoke, are they doing burn out?
3. They are able to drift on straight road and on turns too, how?

Answer (score 1):

For drifting, just tap the brakes once and then turn your car on any side. You don't have to hold the brakes for as long as you are drifting. That way you can drift forever without losing speed.

Comment: OP didn't ask how to drift. They prefaced their question with how they drifted. They wanted to know how some drift mechanics worked.

Comment: @Vemonus Edited the answer a little bit.